# Private key generated by openssl does not satisfy n = p * q

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa

I've generated a key with openssl by using the following command

```
openssl genrsa 1024
```

I've got the following result

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

By using [http://lapo.it/asn1js/](http://lapo.it/asn1js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ve decompiled above `pem` and found out that

```
p = 12716592588957205057720227362856602359162165918588008158928004904780617816265357754968000322907349867949577092305558696339499022301055839537975977118688137

q = 10059832080410675679274931119486090017360564066559599189867309386706046720813347145402059918876964980032136051476889631968099168811652389989474036177869729
```

But in the mean time the modulus

```
n = 127931248913253271289716500205639992466284651287857358177145251825312810367993147780821624164062592337708505486275588028025122128928225266601591073331803580493341719724935049328478344297205955905466581637169109448199715137939448946445804542355907923908845024638480376219852266194827768486624319018352514599977
```

When it should equal:

```
N = 127926786079904340486324750015310657558743663036816604629670248604945247855865212421871439992814824964459404054462886419168595224468110358113599485755243718536935880977456835036272916419632947427885989469252242704342884476060911074859116149906854382812141105735147419775039435625802885168567201322191763704873
```

Why the hell `N` is not equal to `p * q` ?

---

## EDIT:

Here is bunch of keys generated by my openssl, I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks, the first key has correct N, the second one incorrect, I haven't checked the others, but anyway this issue seems to be reproducing, I'm using the following openssl version "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013":

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: bug?? Looks like a few high-order bits of N got screwed up in the output file. The exponents are consistent with p and q.

Comment: Now this is really strange, it doesn't seem like a bug, if I sign a message by hand using `p * q` as a modulus, I get the same result as generated by openssl

Comment: If it's just `n` that's corrupt then OpenSSL should still be able to decrypt/sign successfully, as it doesn't actually use `n` in the process, but instead takes advantage of a faster algorithm using the other fields contained within the private key (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm)

Comment: Yeah I've got it already that it's the CRT that requires all other fields but anyway what does `n` is equal to then?

Comment: Were you able to duplicate this issue Lu4?

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate?

Comment: All of the other keys you posted seem to check out ok when using `openssl rsa -check`, are you sure it's not just a one-off issue (perhaps some sort of disk corruption for the first key you generated?)

Comment: You could run SuperPi and see if your CPU is overheating, causing mathematical calculations to become incorrect. SuperPi will stop and complain of errors if your CPU is at fault.

Comment: I've copy and pasted the corrupted key from console, it wasn't stored on disk

Comment: I don't think that it's possible that CPU may result with `wrong` calculations, there's probably some radiation around that may cause very few memory bits flip, but if cpu was resulting with wrong results of math operations it would either be wrong with memory addressing operations that would cause whole system to corrupt. Also I have read on RSA timing attacks that making it possible to affect the voltage it is also possible to `leak` somehow private key sensitive data, but it's not the case, I was doing ordinary development test, nobody was hacking me...

Comment: Thanks for the bonus Lu4, but I don't think I deserve it. I don't think its deserved because I could not answer your question.

Comment: "Mac OS X Mavericks" - be careful here... I just got bitten with OS X and an OpenSSL-based program because a program was compiled with one version of OpenSSL, but linked with another version of OpenSSL. See [OpenSSL support and Crash in COMP_CTX_free on Mac OS X](http://archives.seul.org/libevent/users/Mar-2014/msg00014.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the hell N is not equal to p * q ?

Confirmed with the key provided. However, I could not duplicate when generating my own key with `openssl genrsa 1024`.

```
$ ./test-rsa.exe

***** P *****
12716592588957205057720227362856602359162165918588008158928004904780617816265357
754968000322907349867949577092305558696339499022301055839537975977118688137

***** Q *****
10059832080410675679274931119486090017360564066559599189867309386706046720813347
145402059918876964980032136051476889631968099168811652389989474036177869729

***** N *****
12793124891325327128971650020563999246628465128785735817714525182531281036799314
77808216241640625923377085054862755880280251221289282252666015910733318035804933
41719724935049328478344297205955905466581637169109448199715137939448946445804542
355907923908845024638480376219852266194827768486624319018352514599977

*** Calc N ***
12792678607990434048632475001531065755874366303681660462967024860494524785586521
24218714399928148249644594040544628864191685952244681103581135994857552437185369
35880977456835036272916419632947427885989469252242704342884476060911074859116149
906854382812141105735147419775039435625802885168567201322191763704873
```

---

```
$ cat test-rsa.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

const char s_key[] = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
"MIICXAIBAAKBgQC2Lh4HLcCR76Wv3oXl6sZ7pv8l9b/66H+I6Bb86tz8RhWCmTCG\n"
"xPVgtZ+w9WutU/rqBHHZOpotX4QDksRD8dRFh6a3HwkIFQdTcDoiD39yNP8F02Gd\n"
"dAl8p/URC5jNCLMSfUK38wMocmoI1I5vqdMNrzUnOup18rl4089Z+faMKQIDAQAB\n"
"AoGBAJrL4z5iWiengxqV8yETBeU8WcJft+n0dapXzHDNAUo8Izr+AIYEBp1Ot4se\n"
"f4igu6zuae80JJ45c2u14p/5dWzN9/URmhTP8xLGjGCjltOJLLyhBPP+ZsLjqu6l\n"
"57MNV6jDqDLdRC66w4NMRCN3FACxcldIC5L6B9OA7UvO1ugBAkEA8s1o6BvufTeD\n"
"ktyOMfW0ZeLGk/6EXp8nf7BIzYhAAPtSt8DegnfYFx2XDgKnYSB15dTDIDMe/KaA\n"
"GcuUb/ZjiQJBAMATb1fFdl7PGccVPgeTaupJayHPySc9PSsACV6VIAnpcU/3NZzd\n"
"MkdIL/JsOsD+1M9uQJqvRZO4qQdjcR5Om6ECQEJGgYlB/pJdcePHomTOvcRF55CE\n"
"G9u8M8rt8qFvvJDICWcxFUulrO16XT4syUWA1825it2iNqYeSL9By63YIokCQBnm\n"
"RPw71xM/r8UleyDAYwlGbxi3EPOmkUnsDldfmltby/ixZ9xIA1CTTkvNBjsh4YY6\n"
"4qE5AxPBMaGaahVhGiECQHyQvXUNE2IUco+ZwmmLnb2ey1s5tBg7i0lEZG47G7GV\n"
"o+yKdJHpToJD8eRJA/2D+pMhQIZm8X/XDIoi1AQ/TRY=\n"
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc), UNUSED(argv);

    int rc;
    FILE* fd = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = NULL;
    RSA* rsa = NULL;
    BIGNUM* n = NULL;
    BN_CTX* ctx = NULL;

    fd = fopen("./key.pem", "w+");
    if(fd == NULL) exit(1);

    rc = fwrite(s_key, 1, sizeof(s_key), fd);
    if(rc != sizeof(s_key)) exit(2);

    rc = fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if(rc != 0) exit(3);

    pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(pkey == NULL) exit(4);

    rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    if(rsa == NULL) exit(5);

#if 0
    fprintf(stdout, "\n***** RSA *****\n");
    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);
#endif

    fprintf(stdout, "\n***** P *****\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", BN_bn2dec(rsa->p));

    fprintf(stdout, "\n***** Q *****\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", BN_bn2dec(rsa->q));

    fprintf(stdout, "\n***** N *****\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", BN_bn2dec(rsa->n));

    n = BN_new();
    if(!n) exit(6);

    ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    if(ctx == NULL) exit(7);

    rc = BN_mul(n, rsa->p, rsa->q, ctx);
    if(rc != 1) exit(8);

    fprintf(stdout, "\n*** Calc N ***\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", BN_bn2dec(n));

    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    BN_free(n);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your point is here - the OP already gave the expected modulus, which is all you seem to have calculated here. The problem is that the modulus stored in the PEM key is *not* `p * q` (which can be easily checked by running it through `openssl rsa -check`, which returns: `RSA key error: n does not equal p q`).

Comment: "The problem is that the modulus stored in the PEM key is not `p * q`" - OK, thanks. That was not clear. I was under the impression the script was performing the multiplication `p * q`.

Comment: Why does n != p * q ?

Comment: "Why does n != p * q" - sorry, I don't know. Can you reproduce it? I could not on my test runs. What version of OpenSSL are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I've tested all 6 private keys you provided in **EDIT** with this command

```
$ openssl rsa -check -in privkey
```

and all of them returns `RSA key ok`. Except the first one, it returns `RSA key error: n does not equal p q`.

My answer to your question

> Why the hell N is not equal to p * q ?

is: **there's no way N is not equal to p*q**. The first key has probably been modified, or has been changed during transmission, so it doesn't pass the rsa check test. Digging into the openssl source code, we can see that `openssl genrsa` command is carried out by

```
int rsa_builtin_keygen(RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e_value, BN_GENCB *cb)
```

in `/crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c`. At ln:289, the modulus `n` is calculated with

```
/* calculate n */
if (!BN_mul(rsa->n,rsa->p,rsa->q,ctx)) goto err;
```

which means n=p*q. You should look for other possibilities that cause your problem, rather than casting doubt on genrsa command.

Comment: @Lu4, broken memory can modify data stored in it (run memtest?). There should be ECC protected memory to store data unmodified all time.