# PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey: Getting RSA key public modulus and exponent

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I'm using PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey function in this way:

```
void test(void)
{
    RSA * privateKey = NULL;
    FILE * fp;

    if(NULL != (fp= fopen("./my_file.key", "r")) )
    {
          privateKey=PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
          if(privateKey==NULL)
          {
              printf("\n\tCould NOT read RSA private key file");
          }
          else
          {
              printf("\n\tRSA structure filled");
          }

         // This is working OK and privateKey is NOT NULL

    }
}
```

Then, I try to retrieve modulus and public exponent to fill them into a personal structure:

```
struct
{
    unsigned char   modulus[256];
    unsigned char   pub_exp[8];
} s;
```

But all accesses I tried (I tried a lot) to privateKey->n will result in a segmentation fault.

for example:

```
unsigned char modulus [2048];
unsigned char exp[2048];
BN_bn2bin(privateKey->n, modulus);  // Segmentation fault results from this call
```

So my question is: how to copy modulus or public exponent from RSA structure to my structure "s" fields?

May someone help about this?
Many thanks,
Regards,

Sylvain

Comment: There's a full OpenSSL/RSA test program called `test-rsa.c` located at [Private key generated by openssl does not satisfy n = p * q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119835/private-key-generated-by-openssl-does-not-satisfy-n-p-q). Does that crash on you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to copy modulus or public exponent from RSA structure

```
int req = BN_num_bytes(rsa->n);
assert(rc > 0);

unsigned char* buff = malloc(req);
assert(buff != NULL);

int rc = BN_bn2bin(rsa->n, buff);
assert(req == rc);
```

Be wary of trying to copy the byte buffers into fixed sized arrays. Someone might come along and get you to copy a 4096-bit modulus into your 2048-bit array.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, unfortunatly, I get a segmentation fault as soon as I run int req = BN_num_bytes(privateKey->n); ... I put this line in my previous function after "RSA structure filled" is printed

Comment: Show the command line you are using to build your program. Also show the output of `openssl version`.

Comment: hey, I found my issue, I also had this warning that I chose to ignore: attention : assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
           privateKey=PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);  I use the line     PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,& privateKey,NULL,NULL);              and I can access 'n'.   Here is my compilation line for info: gcc   -g -O0 -o atmel_test.o -c atmel_test.c
gcc -g -o atmel_test atmel_test.o -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -O0 -g

Comment: Documentation should be updated cause this behavior is NOT the expected one: the PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey returned integer is NOT documented. Many thanks for your help and the needed allocation

Comment: `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey` has always returned a `RSA*`, even in 0.9.8 branch. I expect it has something to do with Cygwin (earlier I thought it was Mac OS X, becuase you'll see odd behavior from there too due to runtime linking against 0.9.8). See, for example, [function PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey not returning](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/function-PEM-read-RSAPrivateKey-not-returning-td3880.html).

Comment: Maybe you got the warning on the `FILE*`, and not the return value.

Comment: Did you #include openssl/pem.h for the correct declaration? If not and with gcc's default -std=gnu89 you get the K&R1 implicit declaration of all functions as 'unknown parameters returning int'. That will warn for the return int, but can't warn on the parameters because it has no clue what type(s) they should be. Even so I'd expect the incorrect conversion to cause a fault only on 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

From OpenSSL 1.1.0 many structures were made opaque and you can no longer do things like look directly at the fields in a struct.
You should use the provided accessor functions instead. Here you can find more infos: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes

---

Acces rsa->n in OpenSSL 1.1.0:

```
RSA *pRsa;
BIGNUM *n;
FILE *pFile = fopen("private.key","r");

pRsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(pFile, NULL, NULL, password);
RSA_get0_key(pRSA, &n, NULL,NULL);

BN_print_fp(stdout, n);
```