# Apple certificate is invalide with PKCS7_verify

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, x509certificate

I download [`AppleRootCertificate.cer`](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) and now I try to check if my in-app receipt certificate is valid (same as apples one).

I do it like apple present in his WWDS videos.

```
    BIO *b_receipt = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[receipt bytes], (long)[receipt length]);
    BIO *b_x509 = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[certificateData bytes], (long)[certificateData length]);

    // Convert receipt data to PKCS #7 Representation
    PKCS7 * p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(b_receipt, NULL);

    // Create the certificate store for matching white Apple cerif.
    X509_STORE * store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509 * appleRootCA = d2i_X509_bio(b_x509, NULL);
    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, appleRootCA);

    // Verify the Signature

    BIO * b_receiptPayload = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    int result = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, b_receiptPayload, 0);
    NSLog(@"Result == %i", result);
```

but the result is always 0 and not 1.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: And what do you get from `ERR_print_errors_fp()` or `ERR_get_error()`? Are you going to make us guess ;) The docs are at [`ERR_print_errors(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html) and [`ERR_get_error(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_get_error.html).

Comment: `x509_verify` might be helpful to you. See [Check that a file is certificate or a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398477/check-that-a-file-is-certificate-or-a-key) for suggestions on verifying keys and certificates.

Comment: Apple makes two roots available for download at http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/: AppleIncRootCertificate.cer and AppleComputerRootCertificate.cer. Is it one of those, or is it a different one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by #noloader I print error whit `ERR_get_error()`.

When I get : `Error:0D0C50A1:lib(13):func(197):reason(161)`, I google it and discovered that I need to add this line above  :

```
 OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

This solve all my problem :D

Comment: Seems like this OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms() mandatory for OpenSSL 1.0.2k, OpenSSL 1.1.1 seems to work without explicit addition of all algs.