# Converting a SSL Cert string into a valid X509_STORE_CTX

Tags: c++, security, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to get both of these certs into a X509_STORE_CTX, but when I go to read them out, they are both NULL. Any ideas?

The certs look like:

```
// Not the real certs. Just trying to illustrate that the certs are just a new line
// delimited string
const char *certA = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGWDCCBUCgAwI......\n.....\n"

SSL_library_init();
SSL_CTX * sslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
X509_STORE *store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(sslCtx);
X509_STORE_CTX *store_ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();

BIO *bio;
X509 *certificate;

/*First cert*/
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_write(bio,(const void*)certA ,sizeof(certA));
certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, certificate);

/*second cert*/
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_write(bio,(const void*)certB ,sizeof(certB));
certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, certificate);

X509_STORE_CTX_init(store_ctx, store, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: You can't convert a X509 certificate into a `X509_STORE_CTX`. What are you really trying to do? This question show you how to verify a certificate via an `X509_STORE_CTX`: [Check that a file is certificate or a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398477/check-that-a-file-is-certificate-or-a-key). Don't let the question's title fool you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(certA)` here will provide just the size of that `const char*` variable, which is the size of a pointer (mostly 4 or 8).

Try declaring the certificate contents as `static const char certA[]` instead.

Also using [BIO_puts()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_puts) and avoiding the `sizeof()` completely might be easier.

Comment: I did that, but when I get "STACK_OF(X509) *stk = store_ctx->untrusted;" stk is null.

Comment: So the variable `certificate` is now at least not NULL anymore after `PEM_read_bio_X509()`?
Also now I see that using `BIO_puts()` without any sizeof()s or other gotchas might be easier.

Comment: Won't `store_ctx->untrusted` be NULL, because you are passing your `store` as 2nd parameter to `X509_STORE_CTX_init()`, which is for the "trusted certificate store" according to the documentation?

Also the source code comment for the field `untrusted` says it's just the input, probably from the 3rd parameter to the init function.