# Loading a PEM format certificate

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

How do I load the PEM format certificate as an x509 in openssl c++?

```
 int SSL_use_certificate(SSL *ssl, X509 *x);
 int SSL_use_certificate_ASN1(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *d, int len);
 int SSL_use_certificate_file(SSL *ssl, const char *file, int type);
```

These are the 3 functions available to add a certificate to a Handle. I have a certificate string inside the program(This is just a PEM formatted data). I want to add it to the handle. How do I proceed?

Will SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb work with private keys that I am loading into and ssl handle and not a context?

Comment: What `Handle`? OpenSSL does not use a handle.

Comment: by handle i mean the SSL*

Answer (score 0):

> How do I load the PEM format certificate as an x509 in openssl c++?

You should probably use `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file`. You can use them and build a client or server context. The sample code is shown below. There are some nuances to using them, so take a look at OpenSSL's documentation at [`SSL_CTX_use_certificate(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html).

I'm not sure what "as an x509" means. The certificate will be x509, but the private key will be PKCS #8. There are `PEM_read_bio_X509` and `PEM_read_X509`, they return an `X509*`, and they may do what you want.

> Will SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb work with private keys that I am loading

It depends, but it should. The password callback is optional. Use it if you password protected the key. In the code below, I call it `PasswordCallback`, and its used for both reading and writing the key (only reading is shown below).

---

```
using SSL_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SSL_CTX, decltype(&::SSL_CTX_free)>;

SSL_CTX* CreateServerContext()
{    
    do
    {
        int rc;
        unsigned long err;

        const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_server_method();
        ASSERT(method != NULL);
        if (method == NULL)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSLv23_server_method failed");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        SSL_CTX_ptr t(SSL_CTX_new(method), ::SSL_CTX_free);
        ASSERT(t.get() != NULL);
        if (t.get() == NULL)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSL_CTX_new failed");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3;
        flags |= SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
        flags |= SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG;
        flags |= SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE;

        /* Cannot fail */
        SSL_CTX_set_options(t.get(), flags);

        string ciphers = GetServerCipherSuites();
        ASSERT(!ciphers.empty());

        rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(t.get(), ciphers.c_str());
        err = ERR_get_error();

        ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list failed");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        string certFile = config.GetServerCertFile();
        ASSERT(!certFile.empty());

        rc = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(t.get(), certFile.c_str());
        err = ERR_get_error();

        ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file failed");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        /* These two do not return a value... cannot fail? */
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(t.get(), PasswordCallback);
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(t.get(), (void*) SERVER_KEY_LABEL);

        string keyFile = config.GetServerKeyFile();
        ASSERT(!keyFile.empty());

        rc = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(t.get(), keyFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
        err = ERR_get_error();

        ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file failed");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        rc = SSL_CTX_check_private_key(t.get());
        err = ERR_get_error();

        ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            LogError("GetServerContext: SSL_CTX_check_private_key failed");
            /* non-fatal, but everything will probably break */
        }

        /* These three do not return a value... cannot fail? */
        SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh_callback(t.get(), DhCallback);
        SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback(t.get(), EcdhCallback);
        SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback(t.get(), ServerNameCallback);

        return t.release();

    } while (0);

    return NULL;
}
```

The idea with the password callback is: OpenSSL provides you a buffer and a size. You fill the buffer, and return the size of how much you filled.

My password callback is somewhat involved. It performs a single hash of the raw password before passing it on to the library. That ensures a "plain text" password is not used (but does not slow down the customary attacks). Yours can prompt the user for a string, or it can return a hard coded string.

My password callback uses a label. The label allows me to derive different keys depending on usage (even though the same 'base' secret is used). By specifying a different usage or label, I get a different derivation of key bits. The label is provided through `arg` below, and you can set it with `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata`.

```
using EVP_MD_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy)>;

int PasswordCallback(char *buffer, int size, int rwflag, void *arg)
{
    UNUSED(rwflag);

    int rc;
    unsigned long err;
    ostringstream oss;

    const char* label = (char*) arg;
    size_t lsize = (label ? strlen(label) : 0);

    SecureVector sv = config.GetMasterKey();
    AC_ASSERT(!sv.empty());
    if (sv.empty())
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_create(), ::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy);
    AC_ASSERT(ctx.get() != NULL);

    const EVP_MD* hash = EVP_sha512();
    AC_ASSERT(hash != NULL);

    rc = EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx.get(), hash, NULL);
    err = ERR_get_error();

    AC_ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx.get(), sv.data(), sv.size());
    err = ERR_get_error();

    AC_ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    if (label && lsize)
    {
        rc = EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx.get(), label, lsize);
        err = ERR_get_error();

        AC_ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            ...
            throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
        }
    }

    int n = std::min(size, EVP_MD_size(hash));
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    rc = EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (unsigned char*) buffer, (unsigned int*) &n);
    err = ERR_get_error();

    AC_ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    return n;
}
```