# Unable to perform CRL check during certificate validation in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to perform Certificate Validation using OpenSSL with CRL Check.

I am able to do it using command prompt with both the below mentioned commands -

```
1. openssl verify -crl_check  -CAfile CA_crl.pem recipient_cert.pem

2. openssl verify -crl_check -CRLfile crls.pem -CAfile CA.pem mycert.pem
```

In the first command CA_crl.pem contains both CA certificate and CRL content. 
And in the second command CA and CRL are mentioned in different files.

Now I want to perform the same operation using C code. I refered to the below link but I keep getting return value 0 from `X509_verify_cert` with no error codes to give any hint.

http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+10.+Public+Key+Infrastructure/10.5+Performing+X.509+Certificate+Verification+with+OpenSSL/

Any pointers to my mistake?

**Update 1:**

I am trying a different approach. This is my curent code. Now I am getting a return value 1 from `X509_verify_cert` but I should be getting error code 12 for `CRL has expired` error.

This is my code now -

```
void printError() {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nPrinting Errors");
    long err = ERR_get_error();
    while (err != 0 ) {
        char buf[130];
        char* ptr = ERR_error_string(err, buf);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nError from buffer: %s", buf);
        err = ERR_get_error();
    }
}
```

//verification code starts.

```
X509* x509 = initialised;
STACK_OF(X509) *certs = initialised;
char* CAfile = initialised;

X509_STORE *cert_ctx=X509_STORE_new();
    if (cert_ctx == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    X509_STORE_set_verify_cb(cert_ctx,cb);

    X509_LOOKUP *lookup=X509_STORE_add_lookup(cert_ctx,X509_LOOKUP_file());

    if (CAfile) {
        i=X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup,CAfile,X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
        if(!i) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nError loading file %s\n", CAfile);
            //BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error loading file %s\n", CAfile);
            //ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            //goto end;
        }
    } else {
        X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup,NULL,X509_FILETYPE_DEFAULT);

    }

    X509_STORE_CTX *csc = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    if (csc != NULL) {
        X509_STORE_set_flags(cert_ctx, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);
        if(X509_STORE_CTX_init(csc, cert_ctx, x509, certs)) {
            X509_STORE_CTX_set_flags(csc, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nCalling X509_verify_cert");
            int i = X509_verify_cert(csc);
            int ret = 0;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                ret=1;
            }

            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nReturn Value: %d", i);
            printError();

            return(ret);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's an example of performing validation with `X509_verify_cert` and `X509_STORE_CTX_get_error` at [Check that a file is certificate or a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398477/check-that-a-file-is-certificate-or-a-key). However, it does *not* use `X509_STORE_add_crl`.

Comment: `-crl_check` (and `-crl_check_all`) appears to have no effect on the `verify` utility. See the source code in `<openssl src dir>/apps/verify.c`. The call to `args_verify` sets `X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK` and/or `X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL` (see `<openssl src dir>/apps/apps.c`), but neither are used in `verify.c`. So it looks like the builtin checks are always performed.

Comment: @jww - I think the arguments -crl_check (and -crl_check_all) do matter . Because I am getting different results in command prompt for with and without -crl_check argument. And I have added the code as you requested.

Comment: @yashdosi did you figure out how to make it work at the end?