# Error when check private key with certificate

Tags: openssl, x509

I'm using EC and trying to create CMS with OpenSSL function `CMS_sign()` and get following error: (X509_F_X509_CHECK_PRIVATE_KEY, X509_R_KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH).

X509 certificate was generated by server side, I just provided public key. How I could get more information about what is wrong with my private key or X509 certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I could get more information about what is wrong with my private key or X509 certificate?

There are a few things you can do (not withstanding your answer of using a correct key pair :).

First, you should run any keys you load through `EC_KEY_check_key`. Loading a key only checks that its well formed `PEM` or `DER` encoded. `EC_KEY_check_key` performs the checks you expect like making sure the base point is on the curve and the public point (public key) is the base point raised to the private exponent (private key).

An example of OpenSSL loading an bad key is at [Private key generated by openssl does not satisfy n = p * q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119835/private-key-generated-by-openssl-does-not-satisfy-n-p-q). In the code provided, an invalid key was loaded. It loaded fine because it was well formed PEM. But `n = p * q` did not hold, which made the key itself invalid.

`EC_KEY_check_key` is kind of lame. It returns 1 if the key is valid, 0 otherwise. Other library provided key checks, like `DH_check_key`, returns a bit mask of failures (like "p is not prime" and "g is not a generator", etc).

If the key is valid, then you can check a certificate under the key. Checking a certificate is answered in [Check that a file is certificate or a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398477/check-that-a-file-is-certificate-or-a-key/22406677#22406677), so I won't repeat it here. The short answer: use `X509_verify` and `X509_verify_cert`. Both return 1 on success and 0 on failure.

You can retrieve `X509_verify`'s failure code through `ERR_get_error`; while you get `X509_verify_cert` failure code from `X509_STORE_CTX_get_error`. The `X509_verify_cert` errors will be from those listed at [X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.html), and include `X509_V_OK` and `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in public key. Public key from X509 certificate doesn't match public key from private key. Question is not useful so someone please close/delete it.

Comment: The question is useful!