# Programmatically verify a X509 certificate and private key match

Tags: c, openssl

I created an RSA key pair using the `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` cipher. The private key is PEM encoded and has a passphrase. This requires a passphrase to be entered by the user.

Here's the create private key call:

```
//Save private key
    bio_priv = BIO_new_file(full_asymKeyFilePath.c_str(), "a+");
    if (PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(
        bio_priv,   //BIO handle
        rsa,        //Key handle
        EVP_aes_256_cbc(),      //Cipher encoding format
        pwd,        //Password
        pwd_len,            //Password length
        NULL,       //Callback
        NULL        //Not sure
        ) != 1) {
            //report err
    }
```

Then I generated a certificate and signed it with the private key.

```
//Sign the certificate with the generated key
    if (!X509_sign(cert, evpKey, EVP_sha1())){
        //report err
    }
```

Later on, I want to verify that this certificate matches this RSA key pair. When I `SSL_CTX_check_private_key()`, I'm prompted to input a passphrase from the console.

**Is there are way to automatically input the password so that I don't get prompted from the console?**

```
//Load server certificate, must be called before ever calling use private key
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(context, full_certFilePath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) == 0){   //load all certs from PEM file into SSL_CTX 
        //err
    }

    //Load private key corresponding to the certificate
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(context, full_asymKeyFilePath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) == 0){ //load all certs from PEM file into SSL_CTX 
        //file type is not pem or private key was loaded before calling this function. Private key does not match the public key in the certificate
        //err
    }

    //Verify that certificate and private key match
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(context)){  //<====== Prompts me to enter pass :(
        //err
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I've discovered SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb() after reading through documentation. I'll try it out and post my progress later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check that a file is certificate or a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398477/check-that-a-file-is-certificate-or-a-key)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Programmatically verify a X509 certificate and private key match. Private key has a PEM passphrase

There are two answers here. One is for the certificate, and the second is for the private key. The private key is shown first because it is used to validate the certificate (so it makes sense to visit it first).

Also, its important to call the `*_check_key` routines because OpenSSL only checks that a key is well encoded; and it does not check that its actually valid. See, for example, [Private key generated by openssl does not satisfy n = p * q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119835/private-key-generated-by-openssl-does-not-satisfy-n-p-q).

---

In OpenSSL, you would use the following to verify the the private key is well encoded:

```c
FILE* file = fopen(...);
EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(file, NULL, PasswordCallback, NULL);
unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();

if(pkey)
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
```

If `pkey` is `NULL`, then there was a problem and `err` holds a reason code. Otherwise, you have a properly encoded private key (but not necessarily valid).

If the key is properly encoded, you can check the type of private key and validate it with the following.

```c
int type = EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey);
switch (type)
{
case EVP_PKEY_RSA:
case EVP_PKEY_RSA2:
    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    rc = RSA_check_key(rsa);
    ASSERT(rc);
    RSA_free(rsa);

    break;

case EVP_PKEY_DSA:
case EVP_PKEY_DSA1:
case EVP_PKEY_DSA2:
case EVP_PKEY_DSA3:
case EVP_PKEY_DSA4:
    DSA* dsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_DSA(pkey);
    rc = DSA_check_key(dsa);
    ASSERT(rc);
    DSA_free(dsa);

    break;

case EVP_PKEY_DH:
    DH* dh = EVP_PKEY_get1_DH(pkey);
    rc = DH_check_key(dh);
    ASSERT(rc);
    DH_free(dh);

    break;

case EVP_PKEY_EC:
    EC_KEY* ec = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey);
    rc = EC_KEY_check_key(ec);
    ASSERT(rc);
    EC_KEY_free(ec);

    break;

default:
    ASSERT(0);
}
```

`EVP_PKEY_get_type` is not part of OpenSSL. Here's how I implemented it:

```c
int EVP_PKEY_get_type(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    ASSERT(pkey);
    if (!pkey)
        return NID_undef;

    return EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
}
```

---

In OpenSSL, you would use the following to verify the the certificate is well encoded:

```c
FILE* file = fopen(...);
X509* x509 = PEM_read_X509(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();
```

If `x509` is `NULL`, then there was a problem and `err` holds a reason code. Otherwise, you have a properly encoded certificate (but not necessarily valid).

You can then verify the certificate with:

```c
/* See above on validating the private key */
EVP_PKEY* pkey = ReadPrivateKey(...);

int rc = X509_verify(x509, pkey);
err = ERR_get_error();
```

If `rc != 1`, then there was a problem and `err` holds a reason code. Otherwise, you have a valid certificate and private key pair. If the certificate is valid, then you can't use `err` because `err` is only valid if there's a problem.

If your certificate is signed by an issuer (for example, a CA or intermediate), then you need to use a `X509_STORE` to verify the issuer's signature on your certificate (a lot of error checking omitted):

```c
const char* serverCertFilename = ...;
const char* issuerCertFilename = ...;    

X509_STORE* store = X509_STORE_new();
ASSERT(store);

static const long flags = X509_V_FLAG_X509_STRICT | X509_V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE
        | X509_V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK;
rc = X509_STORE_set_flags(store, flags);
err = ERR_get_error();
ASSERT(rc);

/* Some other object/functions owns 'lookup', but I'm not sure which (perhaps the store) */
X509_LOOKUP* lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_file());
/* err = ERR_get_error(); // Does not set error codes. */
ASSERT(lookup);    

/* Cannot load this from memory. No API!!! */
rc = X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup, issuerCertFilename, X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
/* err = ERR_get_error(); // Does not set error codes. */
ASSERT(rc);

X509_STORE_CTX* ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
ASSERT(ctx);

X509* serverCert = ReadCertifcate(serverCertFilename);
ASSERT(serverCert);

rc = X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, serverCert, NULL);
ret = err = ERR_get_error();
ASSERT(rc);

/* Error codes at https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.html */
rc = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx);

/* Do cleanup, return success/failure */
```

---

> Is there are way to automatically input the password so that I don't get prompted from the console?

Yes. use the password callback in `PEM_read_PrivateKey`. The `PasswordCallback` can simply provide a password in the buffer, or it can prompt the user and return the password in the buffer.

My password callback is somewhat involved. It performs a single hash of the raw password before passing it on to the library. That ensures a "plain text" password is not used (but does not slow down the customary attacks). Yours can prompt the user for a string, or it can return a hard coded string.

My password callback uses a label. The label allows me to derive different keys depending on usage (even though the same 'base' secret is used). By specifying a different usage or label, I get a different derivation of key bits. The label is provided through `arg` below, and you can set it with `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata`.

```
using EVP_MD_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy)>;

int PasswordCallback(char *buffer, int size, int rwflag, void *arg)
{
    UNUSED(rwflag);

    int rc;
    unsigned long err;
    ostringstream oss;

    const char* label = (char*) arg;
    size_t lsize = (label ? strlen(label) : 0);

    SecureVector sv = config.GetMasterKey();
    ASSERT(!sv.empty());
    if (sv.empty())
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_create(), ::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy);
    ASSERT(ctx.get() != NULL);

    const EVP_MD* hash = EVP_sha512();
    ASSERT(hash != NULL);

    rc = EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx.get(), hash, NULL);
    err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx.get(), sv.data(), sv.size());
    err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    if (label && lsize)
    {
        rc = EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx.get(), label, lsize);
        err = ERR_get_error();

        ASSERT(rc == 1);
        if (rc != 1)
        {
            ...
            throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
        }
    }

    int n = std::min(size, EVP_MD_size(hash));
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    rc = EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (unsigned char*) buffer, (unsigned int*) &n);
    err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(rc == 1);
    if (rc != 1)
    {
        ...
        throw runtime_error(oss.str().c_str());
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it. When I ran:
EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(file, NULL, PasswordCallback, NULL);
I got an the following error:
OPENSSL_Uplink(000000000047E000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
Do you might have an idea why?

Comment: @jww do you know of a way to verify a public key, because according to the docs "it does not work on RSA public keys that have only the modulus and public exponent elements populated"

Comment: @lmiguelmh - as far as I know, the only requirement is `e` and `d` must be co-prime (modulo requirements on `p` and `q`). But you don't have `d`, so you can't really test anything. Maybe you can test `n` is odd.

Comment: @jww thanks! I came up with this solution could you see it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30761216/2692914

Answer (score 0):

Adding some notes to jww's answer.

There is some usage of `EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type)`. if you reference the openssl docs it will state that this is no longer allowed and doing `EVP_PKEY_base_id(pkey)` is the equivalent and is supported in modern openssl libraries.
here is a reference: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_type.html

> Previous versions of this document suggested using EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type) to determine the type of a key. Since EVP_PKEY is now opaque this is no longer possible: the equivalent is EVP_PKEY_base_id(pkey).