# Verify a RSA public key in OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I have an EVP_PKEY with only the public part of a RSA key. I extracted the public part from a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure in DER encoding. This is what I have now:

```
unsigned char publicKey[] = {0x30, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, ...}
size_t publicKeyLength = 92;
unsigned char* publicKeyCopy = new unsigned char[publicKeyLength];
memcpy(publicKeyCopy, publicKey, publicKeyLength);

RSA *rsa;
rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, (unsigned char const **) &pubKey, pubKeyLen);
EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa);
```

I know that you can use [RSA_check_key to verify a RSA private key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_check_key.html) but the docs say that "*It does not work on RSA public keys that have only the modulus and public exponent elements populated*".

So, is it possible to verify a key without the private part? Because as you can see I have *only* the public part of the EVP_PKEY. I wonder, is this even possible? What would you verify in a public part of an EVP_PKEY?

You can see the answer for this question [Programmatically verify a X509 certificate and private key match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855538/programmatically-verify-a-x509-certificate-and-private-key-match) but there the full key is validated (private and public parts).

**Beware**
*The original code posted in this question has a BUG*. This is because internally `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY` uses `d2i_PUBKEY` and `d2i_PUBKEY` uses `d2i_X509_PUBKEY` (in *x_pubkey.c*). If you read the [documentation for d2i_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html) you will see the next *"WARNING: The use of temporary variable is mandatory. A common mistake is to attempt to use a buffer directly..."*. 
So the corrected code will have to use a temporary copy of `publicKeyCopy` and after the use you could safely delete `publicKeyCopy`:

Comment: What you posted looks like (the beginnings of) a 512bit RSA public key. When you say "verify" you mean simply it is well-formed? Or do you mean establish it as "the" public key of a specific public/private pair. The latter involves an private-key-encrypted known-value (a signature usually). Clarify what it is exactly that you're verifying? "The public key" is not an answer. "The public key with regards to...." would be a helpful to know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to know if the public key is well-formed, the client that will use this key only knows that this is a public key and he will use it for encrypt some data. This is the key in DER format http://lapo.it/asn1js/#305A300D06092A864886F70D01010105000349003046024100832E2AE6E38F9C69928DAD2D9DABEFEB6DA8E5F48F114EBC283B838F7DA2B306E6D677414A86E2D2137F397F422C43DB5F8453D2AB12EEF5C5AFFDDD5C267B13020103.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @jww in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885771/2692914. I came up with this solution, I hope it is ok:

```
bool isValidPublicKeyOnly(EVP_PKEY *pkey) {
    //EVP_PKEY_get_type from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885771/2692914
    int type = EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey); //checks nullptr
    if (type != EVP_PKEY_RSA && type != EVP_PKEY_RSA2) {
        //not RSA
        return false;
    }

    RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    if (!rsa) {
        return false;
    }

    bool isValid = isValidRSAPublicKeyOnly(rsa);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    return isValid;
}

bool isValidRSAPublicKeyOnly(RSA *rsa) {
    //from rsa_ameth.c do_rsa_print : has a private key
    //from rsa_chk.c RSA_check_key : doesn't have n (modulus) and e (public exponent)
    if (!rsa || rsa->d || !rsa->n || !rsa->e) {
        return false;
    }
    //from http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?user=guest&pass=guest&id=1454
    //doesnt have a valid public exponent
    return BN_is_odd(rsa->e) && !BN_is_one(rsa->e);
}
```

Comment: What in the world would ever give you the idea a c++ answer will work for a c question? It won't. They are two separate languages (for good reason). People who want/need a c solution do so for those good reasons.

Comment: I think it is trivial to change this code to C code, in fact you could edit the answer. But, why shouldn't I use C++? Could you give some advice, please?

Comment: Then re-write it in C. Specifically your conditional (i.e. `bool Crypto::isValidRSAPublicKeyOnly(RSA *rsa)`

Answer (score 1):

> ***Beware*** The original code posted in this question has a BUG...

I'm just going to comment on this, and show you how to handle it.

```
unsigned char publicKey[] = {0x30, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, ...}
size_t publicKeyLength = sizeof(publicKey);

unsigned char* t = publicKey;
rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &t, pubKeyLen);
```

Internally, the temporary pointer `t` is incremented, so its wasted. It will point to some place after the buffer if everything works as expected. What you should find is `(size_t)t - (size_t)publicKey == publicKeyLength` after the function executes.

Because you used a temporary pointer, the original pointer `publicKey` is still good. And you can use `t` to parse the next key if there are consecutive keys in memory.

There's no need to copy the data.

---

I think a second option is to use a memory `BIO` and `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY_bio`. Something like:

```
BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(publicKey, (int)publicKeyLength);
ASSERT(bio != NULL);

RSA* rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY_bio(bio, NULL);
ASSERT(rsa != NULL);

/* ... */

RSA_free(rsa);
BIO_free(bio);
```

The `get1` bumps the reference count, so you need to call `free` on both the `EVP_PKEY*` and `RSA*`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and I thought it may be prudent to display my solution to this issue. Unlike lmiguelmh's solution, this one does work in C.

```
int checkRsaPublic(RSA *rsa, int debug) {
    if (!rsa) {
        printf("ERROR: RSA key not defined!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    //key
    const BIGNUM *n;
    const BIGNUM *e;
    const BIGNUM *d;

    //factors
    const BIGNUM *p;
    const BIGNUM *q;

    //crt_params
    const BIGNUM *dmp1;
    const BIGNUM *dmq1;
    const BIGNUM *iqmp;

    RSA_get0_key(rsa, &n, &e, &d);
    RSA_get0_factors(rsa, &p, &q);
    RSA_get0_crt_params(rsa, &dmp1, &dmq1, &iqmp);

    if (debug) {
        if (n) {
            printf("n is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(n));
        }
        if (e) {
            printf("e is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(e));
        }
        if (d) {
            printf("d is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(d));
        }
        if (p) {
            printf("p is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(p));
        }
        if (q) {
            printf("q is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(q));
        }
        if (dmp1) {
            printf("dmp1 is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(dmp1));
        }
        if (dmq1) {
            printf("dmq1 is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(dmq1));
        }
        if (iqmp) {
            printf("iqmp is %s\n", BN_bn2hex(iqmp));
        }
    }

    //RSA_check_key : doesn't have n (modulus) and e (public exponent)
    if (d || !n || !e) {
        printf("ERROR: RSA public key not well defined!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (BN_is_odd(e) && !BN_is_one(e)) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ERROR: Invalid public exponent.");
    return 0;
}
```